# Why is this true:$ \nabla \cdot (\vec V \otimes \vec V)=(\vec V\cdot \nabla ) \vec V +\vec V(\nabla\cdot \vec V) \;\;? $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, tensor-products, tensors

Can someone help me why the following is true: $$ \nabla \cdot (\vec V \otimes   \vec V)=(\vec V\cdot \nabla ) \vec V +\vec V(\nabla\cdot \vec V) \;\;? $$

I've thought of the following relation to be possibly useful:
$$(\nabla \cdot \vec {\vec { T}} )_\beta =\sum _\alpha \frac{\partial }{\partial r_\alpha} T_{\alpha \beta }$$ where $\vec {\vec { T}}$ is  an arbitrary tensor of which you take the $\beta ^{th} $ component.

Comment: Have you attempted to write down the left and the right hand side of the equation in component form and then to cancel equal terms? It's clearly a variant of $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}V(x)^2=2V(x)\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}V(x)$. Have you tried to compute it for $V$ being a vector of dimension two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
(\nabla \cdot (\vec V \otimes \vec V))_\alpha &= \sum_\beta \frac \partial {\partial x_\beta} (V_\beta V_\alpha)\\
&= \sum_\beta \left(\frac {\partial V_\beta} {\partial x_\beta}  V_\alpha + V_\beta \frac {\partial V_\alpha} {\partial x_\beta} \right)\\
&= V_\alpha \sum_\beta\frac {\partial V_\beta} {\partial x_\beta} + \left(\sum_\beta V_\beta \frac \partial {\partial x_\beta} \right) V_\alpha \\
&= (\nabla \cdot \vec V) V_\alpha + (\vec V \cdot \nabla) V_\alpha
\end{align}
$$